# Animated container can't use border radius and box shape circle at the same time?

Tags: flutter, animation, button, reshape, flutter-animation

I used the animated container to create a button. When the button is tapped it will turn into a circle at inside the container I am showing a circle progress indicator. Now the issue is when I try to make the container circle with the `shape` property. it throws and error. How can I solve this error.

The error message is

```
Failed assertion: line 129 pos 12: 'shape != BoxShape.circle || borderRadius == null': is not true.
```

**Loading Button:**

```
class LoadingButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoadingButton(
      {super.key,
      required this.status,
      required this.onTap,
      required this.text,
      this.width,
      this.textColor,
      this.backgroundcolor,
      this.margin,
      this.padding});

  final bool status;

  final String text;

  final double? width;

  final Color? textColor;

  final Color? backgroundcolor;

  final EdgeInsetsGeometry? margin;

  final EdgeInsetsGeometry? padding;

  final VoidCallback onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        width: status ? 50 : 200,
        height: 45,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 350),
        padding: padding,
        margin: margin,
        decoration: status
            ? BoxDecoration(
                color: backgroundcolor ?? kGreen, shape: BoxShape.circle)
            : BoxDecoration(
                color: backgroundcolor ?? kGreen,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
        child: status
            ? const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  color: kWhite,
                  strokeWidth: 3,
                ),
              )
            : CommonText(
                text: text,
                size: 14,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                textColor: textColor ?? kWhite,
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you include how you;ve used this widget

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issued by wrapping the animated container with the `ClipRRect` Widget. For some reason we can't give Both the `border radius` and the `BoxShape.circle` to the container at the same time. And when I change the border radius to null. the container didn't changed completely from rectangle to circle.

```
InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          width: status ? 50 : 200,
          height: 45,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 350),
          padding: padding,
          margin: margin,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: backgroundcolor ?? kGreen,
              shape: status ? BoxShape.circle : BoxShape.rectangle),
          child: status
              ? const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color: kWhite,
                    strokeWidth: 3,
                  ),
                )
              : CommonText(
                  text: text,
                  size: 14,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  textColor: textColor ?? kWhite,
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```